# Good morphisms of distinguished triangles: can Neeman's method be applied to the motivic stable homotopy category?

Tags: triangulated-categories, homological-algebra, stable-homotopy, motives

It is well known that non-uniqueness of a cone for a morphism in a triangulated category $C$ makes constructing exact functors (of triangulated categories) a difficult task. In section 3 of his "Some new axioms for triangulated categories" Neeman proposes an alternative axiomatics of triangulated categories (that includes a certain notion of 'good morphism' of distinguished triangles). I wonder whether Neeman's methods can be applied to the motivic stable homotopy category $SH$ of Morel and Voevodsky? Can any better methods for 'rigidifying' (for example, higher categories?) be applied to $SH$?

Upd. It seems that I need an category $G$ whose objects and morphism are morally distinguished triangles in $C$ and their morphisms + some extra data. Any $C$-morphism can be extended to an object of $G$, any commutative square could be extended to a $G$-morphism, whereas for any $G$-morphism of distinguished  triangles $X\to Y\stackrel{v}{\to} Z\stackrel{w}{\to} X[1]$ and $X'\to Y'\stackrel{v}{\to} Z'\stackrel{w'}{\to} X'[1]$ 
that is $0$ on $X$ and $Y$ the corresponinding morphism from $Z$ to $Z'$ equals $v'\circ \theta \circ w$ for some $\theta\in C(X[1],Y')$ (this is the correction of the Neeman's axiom GTR2).

Denis-Charles Cisinski has written some very interesting comments on the relations between various types of 'nice' triangulated categories; yet I wonder which texts treat this topic.

Comment: Doesn't the motivic stable homotopy category come from some nice stable model category (or stable $infty$-category)? If so it should satisfy any reasonable proposed axioms for a triangulated category, since cones upstairs in the model category (or $\infty$-category) are as unique as it makes sense to make them.

Comment: Dear Dylan Wilson, you are probably right. Yet I would prefer to have a proof of this statement. Does you argument yield a way to define (functorially) 'good morphisms of triangles' (so that a commutative square could be extended to a morphism of triangles in a way that is 'unique up to a homotopy')?

Comment: Mikhail, maybe you can make this statement precise and incorporate it to your question. It looks interesting.

Comment: See the remark at the end of section 3 of the referenced paper of Neeman. The argument he gives showing that the stable homotopy category of spectra is "new triangulated" should work equally well in any stable model category (possibly with a few functorial cofibrant or fibrant replacements thrown in).

Comment: Dear Dylan, thank you! Actually, I have read this remark already.:) Do you think that Neeman's argument really (and easily) generalizes to this setting? 

Comment: Dear Fernando, I will try to understand which of Neeman's axioms are required for my purposes; then I will make an update.

Comment: So maybe I should've said "simplicially enriched stable model category" but the rest should be okay. And actually you won't need to do any fibrant or cofibrant replacements since you'll be working in the category of fibrant-cofibrant objects anyway.

Comment: In the following list, each element defines an object of the next kind in the list: Stable model category, Stable $\infty$-category, Grothendieck's triangulated derivator (aka stable homotopy theory in the sense of Heller), filtered triangulated category in the sense of Beilinson (aka $f$-categories), Neeman's triangulated category, Verdier's classical triangulated category. And $SH$ is obtained from a stable model category by construction, isn't it? So you can pick up your favourite structure to work with.

Comment: Another comment: the principle of Neeman's axioms is that we want enough structure to be able to define the cone of a morphism of triangles. But, whenever your triangulated category comes from something in the list above between a stable model category and a filtered triangulated category (included), there is much more than Neeman is asking: there is a genuine triangulated category of distinguished triangles (and this is why Neeman's axioms are very obviously true in this case).

Comment: Dear Denis-Charles, thank you! Are there any references for your statements? In particular, how does one construct a filtered triangulated category for a stable homotopy category?

Comment: @Mikhail, what you ask for in your update is stronger than Neeman's axioms. Neeman's category of good triangles has more objects.

Comment: @Mikhail: Maybe the following reference will help. It's a paper called $f$-categories and Tate Motives. On page 7 they define filtered triangulated categories. On page 8 they show that the filtered derived category is one. I think that proof will go through mutatis mutandis to show the stable homotopy category is one. The point is that $C(\leq 0)$ has a finite decreasing filtration concentrated in negative degrees, $C(\geq 0)$ is defined similarly, the auto-equivalence $s$ is suspension (i.e. shift), and the nat. trans $\iota$ is defined just like in that paper. Here's the pdf:

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uiuc.edu%2FK-theory%2F0913%2Fhead.pdf&ei=i7nDUL3aDu-I0QH8nICYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEOQizs6r29PyY2wMX7zOXqqRKNBg. This was all towards answering your last question of Denis-Charles Cisinski